# On demand resources, the app rejected

Tags: ios, ios9, app-store-connect, itunes-app

My app was rejected several times on the App store.

It is said that In app Purchases where not accessible for Apple's quality engineers.

Therefore, I've redesigned the app, and necessary items were made accessible as ODR resources.

On my local iPhone, I am able to access ODR resources, I see how they are downloaded.

After submitting the app into TestFlight, i.e. when ODR resources are kept on Apple's web servers, everything is OK.

But when I submitted the app for the review,  it was rejected: There is an error , Alert view says, that:

**The requested application data doesn’t exist**

Is it related with Apple Id? Why I can't access ODR resources even from TestFlight app, but for Apple they are not accessable?

Comment: ODR is poorly implemented by Apple, like many other important things on iOS. ODR has a series of bugs that were never solved because Apple don't think they are important. One of the serious bugs of ODR is [this one](https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/7508).

Comment: What workarounds are people using?